How do I create an asset but hide the dependencies upon importing?
I recently watched this blender tutorial to make a tree and I'm trying to make that tree and its leaves particles an asset. With what I've tried so far, when I import the asset, it brings in tree and leaf particles AND the individual leaf image plane as separate entities (See screenshot). I would prefer it only bring in the tree with the particles of leaves, and the individual leaf object is not selectable in the downstream file.
I'm trying to avoid packing resources and Make Instances Real as I imagine that will not be as performant, and packing would dramatically increase the .blend filesize. Am I thinking about that correctly, or would packing and Make Instances Real be the correct route? Thank you for any advice, I really appreciate it.


Solution I've gone with: I shrunk the leaves image down and hid it in the tree trunk. Then I scaled up the rendering of the particles. I'm still interested in what others do regarding this, though.

You can deselect the isolated planes when exporting (export selected only). As for the instances, I doubt that reference system is universal, or can at least be exported to any given extension.

Thank you, I appreciate that info. I will try that with importing. I misspoke in my post I suppose: I'm trying to use the tree and its leaf particles as an Asset via Mark as Asset, and then "importing" via the Asset Browser, not Link or Append

@ahainen To clarify, the asset browser does use the link or append option.

Thank you for that info, @Lutzi. I'm just selecting Mark as Asset from the Outliner, though. I'm unclear how to "deselect the isolated planes" in that situation. I've tried marking the following as an asset: just the tree object (with the particle system), a collection of the tree, a collection of the tree and the leaf image plane. No matter what, the leaf image plane comes along with

@ahainen You can also mark a collection as asset, maybe you can have a subcollection containing the leaf and disabled, and it will stay that way when importing the asset ? I'm not sure.

If you go into the Asset Browser or File Path settings in preferences you can change the Import Method of the asset to Link instead of Append. Which I believe is the behavior you're looking for. If you want all the objects in the scene, and appended and put into their own collections then probably scripting would be the next best bet.

@Jakemoyo Thank you! I changed the File path import setting from Append to Link. Then I moved the leaf png image plane outside of the collection that I had marked as an asset. After that, importing said collection asset via the asset browser has brought in the tree, the leaf particles, and no separate leaf image plane, just as desired.

Awesome I'll put that as the answer then.

If you go into the Asset Browser or File Path settings in preferences you can change the Import Method of the asset to Link instead of Append. This will make it to where you import single (un-editable) instances of an object into your scene from another blendfile, keeping the dependencies in their own file.



I'm confused shouldn't that be "Link" instead of "Append" ?

Lmao, yes. That's what I meant, we had just hashed out the  answer before in the comments and I just threw it together. Silly goose.

haha, classic brain fart. Cheers
